# Multiple ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

[image]

I am totally lost in OrderBy clausules.

**I need this result after ordering: ID's: 8, 5, 2, 1, 4, 6, 7, 3**

Theese rules must be applicated in this order:

- top3 = 1
- top2 = 1
- top1 = 1
- By order ASC, but order "NULL" or 0 to end of line

Is there any possibility to do this ordering?

Thank you all!

Comment: what have you tried so far, show us the query.

Answer (score 2):

I would translate your requirement as:

```
order by
    top3 desc,
    top2 desc,
    top1 desc,
    nullif(`order`, 0) nulls last
```

The last criteria shorts by ascending `order`, while keeping `null`s and `0` values last.

Please note that `order` is a reserved word in all SQL dialects, so not a good choice for a column name.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't support `NULLS LAST`/`NULLS FIRST`.  However, it is easily incorporated into the query:

```
order by top1 desc, top2 desc, top3 desc,
         (ordercol is null or ordercol = 0) asc  -- put these values last
```